# How do I get the user’s device height in a SwiftUI App?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, swiftui

I’m making an app, using Apple’s new framework `SwiftUI`, but I found a problem.

I want to get the height of user’s device. When I ‘m using `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` in the SwiftUI code, Xcode Preview will crash, but with no reason!? When I remove that line of code, the issue disappeared.

So, how do I get the user’s screen height, and use it in `SwiftUI`?

Comment: Why do you need the screen height? Are you trying lay things out? You shouldn't use the screen height directly when laying things out. Instead, use things like `VStack`, `ZStack` etc.

Comment: Irrelative to the needs it should not crash, or, actually, it does not crash - show your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can get sizes in SwiftUI with GeometryReader. This could help with what you are doing, even it is not very well explained. 
But since there so many screen heights in different devices your layout should always be responsive and not fixed.

> It is difficult, if not impossible, to get the size of a view. This is
>   where the GeometryReader comes in. The GeometryReader is similar to a
>   push-out container view in that you can add child views to. It will
>   allow you to inspect and use properties that can help with positioning
>   other views within it. You can access properties like height, width
>   and safe area insets which can help you dynamically set the sizes of
>   views within it so they look good on any size device. --> [www.bigmountainstudio.com](http://www.bigmountainstudio.com)

```
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
          Text("Width: \(geometry.size.width)")
          Text("Height: \(geometry.size.height)") }    
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on multiplatform and in the Xcode selected device as (My Mac) then using UIScreen.main.bounds.height will cause an error. So, to avoid this error and get the device screen height or width for multiplatform in swiftui, you can write this class:

```
class Device {
    static var screen = Device()
    #if os(watchOS)
    var width: CGFloat = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.size.width
    var height: CGFloat = WKInterfaceDevice.current().screenBounds.size.height
    #elseif os(iOS)
    var width: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
    var height: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height
    #elseif os(macOS)
    // You could implement this to force a CGFloat and get the full device screen size width regardless of the window size with .frame.size.width
    var width: CGFloat? = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size.width
    var height: CGFloat? = NSScreen.main?.visibleFrame.size.height
    #endif
}
```

and use it like this:

```
let screenWidth = Device.screen.width
let screenHeight = Device.screen.height
```